# Is there a special name for junk/spam folder?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

In the [Microsoft Graph document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_move),

> The destination folder ID, or the **Inbox**, **Drafts**,
>   **SentItems**, or **DeletedItems** well-known folder name.

For `destinationId`, is there a special name for junk/spam folder? I tried 
Junk, JunkItems, Spam, SpamItems, but neither works.

```
POST /me/messages/{mailId}/move
{
  destinationId: 'Junk'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Destination Id for Junk Email folder is `JunkEmail`.

For a more complete list, refer to [WellKnownFolderName enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername(v=exchg.80).aspx)  MSDN page.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!